# How to test a Oauth2.0 resource of server

Tags: go, go-testing

I want to code the test for validate the right document to reach to the Oauth2.0 of third party server, how should i complete the pseudocode?

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
}

func testAuthServer(t *testing.T) {
    form := url.Values{}
    form.Set(...)

    r := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, authUrl, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
    r.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    // test the auth server

    if w.Code != http.StatusOK {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: You can to assert that the body sent to the server is the expected one? You don't care about the URL of the server?

Comment: Sorry for late, the authUrl is not the local testing server, it is the existing third-party resource.

Comment: You can probably use a tool like gock in this case. I update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on a third party library to mock the resource. You can take a look at [`gock`](https://github.com/h2non/gock).

```
func TestServer(t *testing.T) {
    defer gock.Off()

    authURL := "http://third-party-resource.com"
    form := url.Values{}
    form.Add("foo", "bar")

    // Create the mock of the third-party resource. We assert that the code
    // calls the resource with a POST request with the body set to "foo=bar"
    gock.New(authURL).
        Post("/").
        BodyString("foo=bar").
        Reply(200)

    r, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, authURL, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    r.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    c := http.Client{}
    _, err = c.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    if !gock.IsDone() {
        // The mock has not been called.
        t.Fatal(gock.GetUnmatchedRequests())
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally i use the normal http client to resolve this problem.

```
import (
    "net/http"
}

func testAuthServer(t *testing.T) {
    form := url.Values{}
    form.Set(...)

    authReq := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, authUrl, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
    authReq.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    authClient, _ := http.Client{}
    authResp, _ := authClient.Do(authReq)

    if authResp.Code != http.StatusOK {
        ...
    }
}
```